# How to simplify imports like npm in Angular

Tags: angular, npm

We were using an npm-library `@ng-plus/modal` in Angular. And the imports in the project was something like this.

```
import { Modal, Toast, Alert } from '@ng-plus/modal';
```

Now, we have decided to modify and it lives as a project library under the `project/ngplus-modal` folder in our app.

> The problem we are facing is with imports.

We already defined `paths` for the project `@modal`. We tried replacing the import with the following which does not work.

```
// Did not work for us: (Desired behaviour)
import { Modal, IModal, Toast, Alert } from '@modal';
```

What works is the following:

```
import { Modal } from '@modal/lib/components/modal.component';
import { Toast } from '@modal/lib/components/toast.component';
import { IModal } from '@modal/lib/interfaces/imodal.interface';
```

> However, our problem is that the library is already implemented in
>   100+ files and not it is just components, but models and interfaces which are
>   scattered throughout the library. How can this be organized like an
>   npm import?

```
import { Modal, IModal, Toast, Alert } from 'package';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine all components in single export definition "index.ts", like:

```
export * from "lib/components/modal.component";
export * from "lib/components/toast.component";
```

And put this file in root of your tree:

- index.ts
- lib

  - components

    - modal..
    - toast...

After that you can easily import with your approach:

```
import { Modal, IModal, Toast, Alert } from '@modal';
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a file inside @modal directory called index.ts and fill it with this:

```
export * from '@modal/lib/components/modal.component';
export * from '@modal/lib/components/toast.component';
export * from '@modal/lib/interfaces/imodal.interface';
```

And the rest of components should work without any issue.